# highcharts bar chart square legend

Tags: highcharts

I could not find a solution to make bar chart legend turn from round to square. I saw a lot of solutions for line charts, which don't work for bar or pie charts. squareSymbol true doesn't work.

```
legend: {
    layout: 'vertical',        
    align: 'right',
   squareSymbol: true,
    verticalAlign: 'middle',      
    floating: false,
    borderWidth: 0,
    backgroundColor: ((Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColor) || 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0)'),
    shadow: false,

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can make the legend bullet points squared by setting the `symbolRadius` to 0.

```
legend: {
       symbolRadius: 0
    },
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0er2fop9/)

Answer (score 1):

Set `symbolRadius` property to `0`:

```
legend: {
    symbolRadius: 0
}
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/humnzs3j/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/legend.symbolRadius